# How to temporarily remove items from a ChoiceBox (or maybe a ComboBox)?

Tags: combobox, javafx, scenebuilder

I've come across a somewhat perplexing conundrum. I've recently started to figure out how to work with listeners, thanks to some people on here, and I'm trying to find a way to use them in conjunction with choice/comboboxes to do something tricky. What I want to have happen is, when the user makes a selection from one of six linked boxes containing six choices, it removes that option from the other 5 boxes until either A: the option is changed to one of the remaining ones, or B: the option is changed to a null or default setting (to prevent getting "locked in" after picking, or maybe I can just make a reset button for that purpose). I've got a ChangeListener on each choicebox now, but various things I've tried (switch statements, assigning each answer a boolean, various attempts to use .getItems().remove() in vain, I've been at this a while) Has anyone figured or seen an example of how this could be done? Thanks in advance for any advice, you guys(and gals) have helped me learn by leaps and bounds these past few weeks.

Comment: To clarify: you have a collection of `ChoiceBox`es, all of which share the same underlying list of items. When an item is selected in any one of them, you want it to be unavailable in the others (so effectively an item can only be selected in one `ChoiceBox` at a time), is that right?

Answer (score 1):

if you want something like this:

[image]

I had this code in my program. it is nor really efficient, but was fine for me on a small set of data.

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ConnectedComboBox<T> implements ChangeListener<T> {

    private ObservableList<T> items;
    private List<ChoiceBox<T>> comboBoxList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ConnectedComboBox(ObservableList<T> items){
        this.items = items;
        if (this.items == null) this.items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    public void addComboBox(ChoiceBox<T> comboBox){
        comboBoxList.add(comboBox);
        comboBox.valueProperty().addListener(this);
        updateSelection();
    }

    public void removeComboBox(ChoiceBox<T> comboBox){
        comboBoxList.remove(comboBox);
        comboBox.valueProperty().removeListener(this);
        updateSelection();
    }

    // this boolean needed because we can set combobox Value in updateSelection() 
    // this will trigger a value listener and update selection one more time => stack overflow
    // this behavior occurs only if we have more than one equal item in source ObservableList<T> items list.
    private boolean updating = false;
    private void updateSelection() {
        if (updating) return;
        updating = true;

        List<T> availableChoices = items.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (ChoiceBox<T> comboBox: comboBoxList){
            if (comboBox.getValue()!= null) {
                availableChoices.remove(comboBox.getValue());
            }
        }

        for (ChoiceBox<T> comboBox: comboBoxList){
            T selectedValue = comboBox.getValue();
            ObservableList<T> items = comboBox.getItems();
            items.setAll(availableChoices);

            if (selectedValue != null) {
                items.add(selectedValue);
                comboBox.setValue(selectedValue);
            }
        }

        updating = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue) {
        updateSelection();
    }
}
```

And here is how you use it:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainFX extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.setSpacing(10);
        ObservableList<String> values = FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four","Five");
        ChoiceBox<String> combo1 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        combo1.setPrefWidth(100);
        ChoiceBox<String> combo2 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        combo2.setPrefWidth(100);
        ChoiceBox<String> combo3 = new ChoiceBox<>();
        combo3.setPrefWidth(100);
        root.getChildren().addAll(combo1,combo2,combo3);

        ConnectedComboBox<String> connectedComboBox = new ConnectedComboBox<>(values);
        connectedComboBox.addComboBox(combo1);
        connectedComboBox.addComboBox(combo2);
        connectedComboBox.addComboBox(combo3);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,600,600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been tinkering with your example for a while, but now I'm running up against another issue, this sits titular error, a stack overflow. The only two major difference between what I've done and your example is that: 1. I'm using an FXML Controller, so I put the ObservableList<String>, the ConnectedComboBox<String>, and all the (six) connectedComboBox.addComboBox(blahblah) into the initialize method in the controller. 2. I've changed the parameters of values from "One", "Two", etc to the parts of an array, I did this by using the following (running out of space):

Comment: Okay so I can't Line Break in comments to save my life, so this is gonna look terrible.

Comment: int[] rollList = new int[6];

Comment: for(blahblah) //A for loop that initiates rollList to all 0s

Comment: ObservableList<String> values = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Null", Byte.toString(rollList[1]), Byte.toString(rollList[2])... etc, etc

Comment: Okay, I've got it sort of figured out, I was populating the choicebox with random numbers between 7-18, and if I rolled the same number twice and picked one of the two, the code would remove both instances of the number, and somehow that was causing the stack overflow. I've since added "" "Roll One(or Two, Three, etc) " + "" in front of each roll, which keeps the stack overflow error from occuring, but now I don't know how I can parse the result to get the value for doing math to.

Comment: I added `boolean updating` in above code to solve your problem with multiple equal items and  stack overflow, so you can just put integers in combobox and use `comboBox.getValue()`